# How to load page with particular scroll position for form submition with JavaScript disabled

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

I've got a newsletter subscription form on my site (just one field, email), built with node.js and express. If JavaScript is enabled, the email is submitted with AJAX and a reply is sent back and a simple 'Success!' message is rendered client side, cute animation and everything.

If JavaScript is disabled, then the data is submitted to the same page the user is currently on, but the page loads at the top. I'd like to render error or success messages where the subscription form is (scrolled down slightly, or on mobile, scrolled down quite a bit).

Is there any way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an `id` to the element, which you want the page to be scrolled to. Example:

```
<form id='someID'></form>
```

and then just redirect to:

```
'http://yoururl.com/some/page#someID' <--- the #someID part is focusing the element and scrolling to it
```

So you can just submit to the same page, like now, but with `#someID` at the end.

Comment: Brilliant. Now, to work out good names for these things. Good semantics are so hard!